# Explicit image of $A_5$ inside $PGL(2,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation

The list of finite subgroups of $PGL(2,\mathbb{C})$ is well known. The cyclic subgroups are easily written down. I was wondering if it is possible to explicitly write down a finite subgroup which is isomorphic to $A_5$. I tried with a presentation of $A_5$ given by

$$
A_5 = \{x,y\ |\ x^5=y^2=(xy)^3=1\},
$$

and tried to find elements of $PGL(2,\mathbb{C})$ which satisfy this relation but I was not successful. What am I missing here? Is there an easier way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You wrote "the finite subgroup which is isomorphic to $A_5$", but there are many such subgroups. Yes, it is possible to write one of them down. Do you just want to see an example?

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, I just want to see an example. As I understand, there is only one example upto conjugation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\omega$ be a primitive fifth root of $1$. By a back of the envelope calculation, using traces, I came up with

$$ x \mapsto \left( \begin{array}{cc}\omega&0\\0&\omega^{-1}\end{array}\right),\ \ \ \ 
x^{-1}y \mapsto \left( \begin{array}{cc}a&b\\1&d\end{array}\right),
$$

where $a = 1/(\omega^2-1)$, $b=-a^2-a-1$, $d=-1-a$, and the images are of course to be understood to be modulo the scalar matrices.

Comment: I did some computations using python, but it seems that $y^2\neq 1$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, the second matrix is the image of $x^{-1}y$, not $xy$ - try again!

Comment: I am getting $y^2 = -1$

Comment: Yes, so that's correct.

Comment: Ah, modulo scalar matrices... Yes thank you